# How to know if this double integral integrates to 0

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like some help to find out if the value of this double integral is $0$ or not. I do not think it is:

$$\int_0^1\int_{-1}^1e^{x^2+y^2}\sin(y)\,dx\,dy$$

Separating the integrals with respect to $x$ and to $y$. I could see by using the power series expansion of $e^{x^2}$ that $\int_{-1}^1e^{x^2}dx$ is positive.

What is an easy way to see that $\int_0^1e^{y^2}\sin(y)\,dy$ is not $0$?

Comment: If you swap $\mathrm dx$ and $\mathrm dy$ then you get $0$ though.

Comment: The integrand is positive.

Comment: @Surb http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1+int_(-1)%5E1+e%5E(x%5E2%2By%5E2)+sin(y)+dy+dx

Comment: @Surb If you do swap $dx$ and $dy$ (without swapping the integral signs, so that it is $y$ which goes from $-1$ to $1$), then the substitution $y\mapsto -y$ gives you the exact same integral with a minus sign in front. Thus the integral is equal to its own negative, and must be $0$. Alternatively, the integrand is odd in $y$, so integrating over an area symmetric across the $y$-axis must yield $0$. That's what Kenny Lau means.

Comment: "What is an easy way to see that $\int_0^1 e^{y^2}sin(y) \ dy$ is not 0??" To check that the integrand is positive on $(0,1)$. Is this your question?

Comment: @Arthur so this actually integrantes to 0?

Answer (score 0):

$e^{y^2} \sin(y) > 0$ when $y \in (0,1]$, and $\mu((0,1]) = 1 > 0$, where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 0):

An integral of the form

$$\int_a^b f(x) \textrm dx $$

Is zero if

- $f(x)=0 \forall x\in [a,b]$, or
- if the surface of all areas with $f(x)>0$ equals the surface of all areas with $f(x)<0$ in the respective integral domain $[a,b]$.

The integral you wonder about is:

$$\int_0^1e^{y^2} \sin(y)\textrm dy, $$

And the function here is always positive in the domain $[0,1]$. Hence, the integral will not be zero.

Be aware, however, that it is unclear which limits belong to which variable. It might be better to write

$$\int_{-1}^1\textrm dx\int_0^1\textrm dy\, e^{x^2+y^2} \sin(y), $$

which is bigger than zero, or

$$\int_{-1}^1\textrm dy\int_0^1\textrm dx\, e^{x^2+y^2} \sin(y), $$

which equals zero